# undefined reference to vtable for inheriting classes

Tags: c++, linker, g++, neural-network, ld

I'm trying to develop a neural network in c++.

I refactored my code utilizing class-inheritance, to allow me to have different kinds of layers, whose neurons could be iterated over in sequence.

My problem is, that my linker (ld invoked by g++) complaines about undefined references to vtables and typeinfo-objects.

As far as I know, the error "undefined reference to `vtable for class`" comes from not implemented pure virtual methods in base classes, but unfortunately I not was able locate the error more percisely.

make all:

```
g++ -Wall -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++11 -w   -c -o Test2dSparselyNeuralNet.o Test2dSparselyNeuralNet.cpp
g++ -Wall -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++11 -w   -c -o NeuralNet.o NeuralNet.cpp
g++ -Wall -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++11 -w   -c -o Sparsely2dNeuralNetwork.o Sparsely2dNeuralNetwork.cpp
g++ -Wall -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++11 -w   -c -o Connection.o Connection.cpp
g++ -Wall -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++11 -w   -c -o Layer2d.o Layer2d.cpp
g++ -Wall -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++11 -w   -c -o Neuron2dIterator.o Neuron2dIterator.cpp
g++ -Wall -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++11 -w   -c -o input/2dinput/cross/cross.o input/2dinput/cross/cross.cpp
g++ -o bin/neural_net_2d     Test2dSparselyNeuralNet.o NeuralNet.o Sparsely2dNeuralNetwork.o Connection.o Layer2d.o Neuron2dIterator.o input/2dinput/cross/cross.o 
Layer2d.o: In function `Layer::Layer()':
Layer2d.cpp:(.text._ZN5LayerC2Ev[_ZN5LayerC5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for Layer'
Layer2d.o: In function `Iterator::Iterator()':
Layer2d.cpp:(.text._ZN8IteratorC2Ev[_ZN8IteratorC5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for Iterator'
Layer2d.o: In function `Layer::~Layer()':
Layer2d.cpp:(.text._ZN5LayerD2Ev[_ZN5LayerD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for Layer'
Layer2d.o:(.rodata._ZTI7Layer2d[_ZTI7Layer2d]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Layer'
Neuron2dIterator.o:(.rodata._ZTI16Neuron2dIterator[_ZTI16Neuron2dIterator]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Iterator'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [neural_net_2d] Error 1
```

makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS =  -Wall -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++11 -w
CXXFLAGS_DEBUG = -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++11 -w

SAMPLES =   input/2dinput/cross/cross.o
OBJS =      Test2dSparselyNeuralNet.o NeuralNet.o Sparsely2dNeuralNetwork.o Connection.o Layer2d.o Neuron2dIterator.o ${SAMPLES}

LIBS =

TARGET =    neural_net_2d   

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o bin/$(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

all:    $(TARGET)
debug:      $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o bin/$(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(CXXFLAGS_DEBUG)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Layer.h

```
#ifndef LAYER_H
#define LAYER_H
#include "Neuron.h"
#include "Iterator.h"

class Layer
{
protected:
    // biasNeuron
    Neuron biasNeuron = 1.0;


    public:
        inline Layer() : biasNeuron(1.0) {}


        virtual Iterator& start();

        virtual Neuron& front(void);
        virtual Neuron& back(void);
        virtual int size();

    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // LAYER_H
```

Layer2d.h

```
#ifndef LAYER2D_H
#define LAYER2D_H

#include "Layer.h"

class Layer2d : public Layer
{
    public: std::vector<std::vector<Neuron> > _neurons;

    public:
        Layer2d();
        virtual ~Layer2d();


        Iterator& start();

        Neuron& front(void);
        Neuron& back(void);
        int size();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // 2DLAYER_H
```

Layer2d.cpp

```
#include "Layer2d.h"

#include "Neuron2dIterator.h"

class Neuron2dIterator;

Iterator& Layer2d::start(void)
{
    Neuron2dIterator& it = (*new Neuron2dIterator(*this));

    return it;
}

Neuron& Layer2d::front(void)
{
    Neuron& frontNeuron = this->_neurons.front().front();

    return frontNeuron;
}
Neuron& Layer2d::back(void)
{
    Neuron& backNeuron = this->_neurons.back().back();

    return backNeuron;
}

int Layer2d::size(void)
{
    int size = this->_neurons.back().size() * this->_neurons.size();

    return size;
}


Layer2d::Layer2d()
{
    //ctor
}

Layer2d::~Layer2d()
{
    //dtor
}
```

LineLayer.h

```
#ifndef LINELAYER_H
#define LINELAYER_H

#include "Layer.h"

#include "Neuron.h"
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

class LineIterator;

class LineLayer : public Layer
{
    public: std::vector<Neuron> _neurons;
    public:
        LineLayer();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // LINELAYER_H
```

LineLayer.cpp

```
#include "LineLayer.h"


#include "LineIterator.h"


Iterator& LineLayer::start()
{
    LineIterator& it = (*new LineIterator());

    return it;
}

Neuron& LineLayer::front()
{
    Neuron& frontNeuron = this->_neurons.front();

    return frontNeuron;
}
Neuron& LineLayer::back()
{
    Neuron& backNeuron = this->_neurons.back();

    return backNeuron;
}

int LineLayer::size()
{
    return this->_neurons.size();
}
LineLayer::LineLayer()
{
    //ctor
}

LineLayer::~LineLayer()
{
    //dtor
}
```

Thnx for help!

Comment: `(*new LineIterator());` Oh my fu..ng god. You know what are you doing? Try to not copy-paste code from Java-like languages and "translate" it to C++

Comment: I'll consider using templates in order to get rid of the heap-allocation for the Iterators. I.e. return iterators from begin(), end() methods by value and use templates for the loops/functions that use the iterators. I think this would be a performance gain, since I use the iterators in extensive loops. Do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: dont you just love when someone comes in, flames you about something, downvotes you, and then leaves... not helping. If you are going to do the first step, then consider not doing those two middle steps and actually /try/ to do the last step, that is what turned me off to even ever asking another question on this site (its not like you can go out and get an secondary account which you keep that has like -99999 rep because you asked a few questions someone else thought was 'stupid' or told you to 'rtfm' which is funny because they dont tell you 'wtfm' is -- of course i dont do this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained at https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#missing_vtable the vtable will be in the same object file as the first non-inline virtual function, which is `Layer::start`. You haven't defined that function, so the compiler never generated the vtable.

> To fix the linker error be sure you have provided a definition for the first non-inline virtual function declared in the class.

Comment: Thanx! I added function definitions for the virtual function declarations in Iterator.h and Layer.h and it compiled!

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed. I was also implementing an iterator.